# Blender performing very poorly

Tags: performance

I'm trying to follow the tutorials, but the program is freezing up and lagging very often and very severely to the point that I can't do some of the steps of the tutorials such as sculpting because I can't see my edits in real-time. Even simple edits, like switching modes, selecting, and duplicating, that happen instantly in the videos, can take up to a minute to do, or even freeze the entire program. I've already followed a few advice threads on here and reddit, but none have helped, and people I've asked in other places seemed stumped as to why blender is so slow. From the responses I got, people are running much more complex projects on weaker specs without any issues, and I can't even get through the donut tutorial.

Specs:

RTX 2060 6gb

Ryzen 5 3600x 3.8 GHZ 6-core

16gb ram

Thanks.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? Which version of Blender?

Comment: If you're using a Subdivision Surface modifier, be careful with the level of subdivisions - anything higher than 3 is most often unnecessary. Beyond that level, the polycount starts getting very high, very quickly, and can easily result in a mesh that causes lagging and stuttering, even on high end machines.

Comment: If you're on Windows, try Sysinternals Process Explorer to see if there are other non-Blender tasks eating RAM/CPU.

Comment: @joaulo Windows 10, and my blender version is 2.90.1

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I *did* try in the past to set the level lower, and it helped, but the model itself is still visibly not smooth, especially in sculpt mode. I'll start the tutorial again to see if I missed something.

Comment: @amonroejj Not sure if I'm using this thing correctly, but it mostly shows background applications like discord, steam, etc.. Nothing too groundbreaking